# What is the meaning of "term" and "condition"?

Tags: contract-law

Whenever installing software you see "click yes to accept the terms and conditions". What is the actual meaning of a 'term' and 'condition'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A term is a condition for which termination of the contract is a redress for breach. A condition that is not a term (i.e. the breach does not allow the aggrieved party to terminate; they can only recover damages) is a warranty. Which is which turns on the facts of each case.

Comment: Why would something be a condition and not a term?

Comment: This could be worded better and include _Tramways_ as an Australian citation. The correct answer should also probably cite UK and US precedent.